# Storing different user permissions in databse with customizations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, permissions

In a custom user permissions, we have something like:

```
  UserId        permission
 11100001        ViewThis
 11100001        ViewThat
 11100002        EditThis
 11100003        EditThat
```

Now, we want `ViewThis` to be more customized, for example to target a specific cost center, so a certain user can only view employees from a certain cost center(s). So I added a column `CostCenter`. If it's `NULL` then it means the user can view all cost centers. The problem now some other permissions, for example `ViewThat` needs to be customized as well, the problem is the customization or limitation does not target a certain cost center, it does target other factors, for example a contract type. So users with the permission `ViewThat` should be limited to employees with certain contract type. So I added another column `ContractTypeID`. This column should be ignored in permissions where this field is not required. Sometimes a certain permission requires two or more of the customization/limitation fields.

The problem now, the table is growing horizontally whenever I need to add a customization/limitation to a permission. Is there a better way or best practice in dealing with such dilemma?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to normalize this out in a data model. Let me show you an example:

[image]

Tables `User` and `Permission` are clear, I guess. In `Accessible` you store the things you want to restrict access to: `CostCenter`, `ContractType`, ...

From your description I understand that you want to define specific combinations of Accessibles and Permissions (*ViewThis* on *CostCenter*, *ViewThat* on *ContractType*, etc.). So you can define these combinations in `AccessiblePermission`.

When you've got these combinations you can assign them to Users in `UserAccessiblePermission`.

This is the *definition* part of the authorization.

The *enforcement* part of the authorization should consist of business logic that grants ***all*** permissions on ***all*** accessibles for which a users has no specific permissions. When there is a specific permission, the authorization changes into ***none, except***.

This is just one way to go about this. I'd be surprised if it matched all your requirements 100%, but I hope it gives some direction.

Answer (score 0):

A relational database may not actually be your best bet.  Your data sounds very unstructured, which is a better fit for xml or a NoSQL database where you just store key/value pairs.  Normally, you can store users, roles, and a users_to_role table where the role table only holds the name of the role which you then check in your code.

If you are stuck with a relational database, you can create a table for every role.  Each table would refference a user and the permissions it grants.  So a ViewThis table that has a user id and a CostCenter.  This would make it harder to add new permissions since you would have to create a new table, but you already have to add columns all the time.  This just isolates each permission and keeps it more focused in a table.

Answer (score 0):

This is my typical setup for managing user permissions. It looks a lot like yours except I make my permissions and roles more granular...

```
actions
    id              varchar(50)
    description     varchar(200)

+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    id         | description                                            |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| VIEW_CC1_ACCT | Allow users to view Cost Center 1 accounting employees |
| VIEW_CC1_HR   | Allow users to view Cost Center 1 HR employees         |
| VIEW_CC1_IT   | Allow users to view Cost Center 1 IT employees         |
| VIEW_CC2      | Allow users to view Cost Center 2 employees            |
| ............. | ...................................................... |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------+

roles
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(50)

+----+--------------------------------+
| id | description                    |
+----+--------------------------------+
|  1 | Cost Center 1 Accounting Clerk |
|  2 | Cost Center 1 HR Manager       |
|  3 | Director of HR                 |
| .. | .............................. |
+----+--------------------------------+

roles_actions
    id              unsigned int(P)
    role_id         unsigned int(F roles.id)
    action_id       varchar(50)(F actions.id)

+----+---------+---------------+
| id | role_id | action_id     |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  1 |       1 | VIEW_CC1_ACCT |
|  2 |       2 | VIEW_CC1_HR   |
|  3 |       3 | VIEW_CC1_ACCT |
|  4 |       3 | VIEW_CC1_HR   |
|  5 |       3 | VIEW_CC1_IT   |
|  6 |       3 | VIEW_CC2      |
+----+---------+---------------+

users
    id              unsigned int(P)
    username        varchar(32)(U)
    password        varchar(123) // Hashed, like my potatoes
    ...

+----+----------+----------+-----+
| id | username | password | ... |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
|  1 | bob      | ******** | ... |
|  2 | april    | ******** | ... |
|  3 | grant    | ******** | ... |
| .. | ........ | ........ | ... |
+----+----------+----------+-----+

users_roles
    id              unsigned int(P)
    user_id         unsigned int(F users.id)
    role_id         unsigned int(F roles.id)

+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | role_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       1 |
|  2 |       2 |       2 |
|  3 |       3 |       3 |
| .. | ....... | ....... |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Is there any reason you can't follow this approach? I only showed examples for Cost Centers but it would work the same for Contract Types or any other restriction you need to add - just create the appropriate `actions`, `roles` and `roles_actions` then re-assign the affected `users` to the new `roles`.

Comment: This will be difficult for a company with 30 or 40 different CCs... and 30 or 40 different types of permissions. I will end up with (40x40) different types of permissions.

Comment: @HaLaBi - I agree that 900-1600 possible `actions` would be a lot to manage, but surely not every single permutation would have to be created? And if every possible permutation IS needed any solution you come up with will have to address all 900-1600 possibilities. At that point it becomes a matter of "What's the easiest way to manage 900-1600 binary flags for every user?" I think the most I've needed to manage is around 450 options. Careful naming of `actions` and a handy jQuery-enhanced interface made it fairly easy to manage. Good luck!